# Distribution of Elliptic Curve Generators over Q

Tags: elliptic-curves

Considering elliptic curves over Q with positive discriminant and rank>0, are there any results or proposed heuristics regarding the fraction of generators that are located on the identity vs non-identity component? How does this vary with rank?

The family of curves I've been examining (associated with $a/(b+c) + b/(a+c) + c/(a+b) = N$) have the following distributions for N even:

```
Rank 1: 313 have generator on identity, 601 on non-identity
Rank 2: 107 have 2 on identity, 153 have 1, 16 have 0
Rank 3: 3 have 3 on identity, 16 have 2, 3 have 1, 0 have 0
```

For N odd, all of the generators appear on the identity component.

Comment: I think there is a result saying that there is no non-trivial rational point for $N$ odd. Also, I don't understand what you mean by "have 2 on identity", etc. It seems to me that it only makes sense to say whether there is a generator on the non-identity component: if $P, Q$ is a set of generators, then $P, P + Q$ also. This is equivalent to asking whether $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is contained in the identity component.

Comment: Did you try to see where the generators are located for, say, the family of all elliptic curves of rank 1, positive discriminant and trivial torsion?

Comment: Of course, $E(\mathbb{Q})_{tors}$ should a priori be contained in the identity component, for this to make sense.

Comment: Sorry, now I remember that the result for $N$ odd is that this equation doesn't have solutions in positive integers, which is equivalent to saying that all rational points are located on the identity component.

Comment: Yes, thanks, you are correct that it only makes sense to ask if there is a generator on the non-identity component.

Comment: You are asking if $E(\mathbb{Q})/2E(\mathbb{Q})\to E(\mathbb{R})/2E(\mathbb{R})$ is surjective. Maybe one can say something about the image of the $2$-Selmer group instead; there might be reasons that other local conditions impose the same as the real condition. Instead for the actual rational points, I doubt it is easy to say much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I gathered some statistics using the [Cremona tables](https://johncremona.github.io/ecdata/). There are 565803 elliptic curves with rank 1, trivial torsion group, positive discriminant (which means that the group of real points has two connected components) and conductor $\leq 4 \times 10^5$ (the current limit of the tables). Among them 239106 curves have the generator of $E(\mathbf{Q})$ located on the identity component.

Here is the histogram representing the location of the generator $P$ on the identity component for these curves. More precisely, this is the distribution of the (unique) real number $z_P \in (0,1/2)$ such that the Mordell-Weil group $E(\mathbf{Q})$ is generated by the class of $z_P \Omega_E^+$, where $\Omega_E^+$ is the real period of $E$. We can note the behaviour near $z=0,1/4,1/3,1/2$ which might be explained by the fact that the torsion points somehow repel the point of infinite order.

[image]